# How to group props and make code more readable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is this the only way of defining properties?

```
        <YAxis
            id="axis1"
            label="Requests"
            style={{ labelColor: scheme.requests }}
            labelOffset={-10}
            min={0}
            max={1000}
            format=",.0f"
            width="60"
            type="linear"
        />
```

This can be really cluttered if there is a long list of properties
It remembers me a bit of inline css, which can become hard to read.

can't we just say:

`var yAxis_props = ( id = ...  label = ... )`

and then insert them like:

`<YAxis yAxis_props />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes can do that, define `yAxis_props` as an object with all the key-values. Like this:

```
var yAxis_props = {
  id: '',
  label: ''
}
```

Then using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) pass all the values as a separate prop, like this:

```
<YAxis
  {...yAxis_props}
/>
```

Check [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes).

---

Ok, you are getting confused between these two ways:

```
// first way
<Component id='', label='' />

// second way
const obj = { id:'', label: ''}
<Component {...obj} />
```

Behind the scene both are same. Check this **[Babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=PTAEAECsGcA9QE4FMCGBjALgKCwMwK4B2mAlgPaGgDCZAtgA4VKEYCCoAFAJSgDeWoQcgz4EhDqAA8AExIA3AHwAJJABtVZScFmLQXLAF8cBYhnKUaDJiwBC3PgKFIRYzo4CQ7mfIWPB_z0l2EmkAXgByFHDQVRQAIzUIuOjgX390wPZeADpc3hCALkjwgBoY-LUi5IMDUFS_DK0dNMF9IyA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.4&externalPlugins=)** output of these two ways. We write `jsx`, which will be converted into `React.createElemet(component/html tag, props, children)`.

Code:

```
function ComponentA () {
   return( <div>Hello</div> )
}

function ComponentB() {
   return (
        <div>
            <A id='a' label='b' />
            <A {...{id:'a', label:'b'}} />
        </div>
   )
}
```

Converted form:

```
function ComponentA() {
  return react("div", null, "Hello");
}

function ComponentB() {
  return react(
    "div",
    null,
    react(A, {
      id: "a",
      label: "b"
    }),
    react(A, {
      id: "a",
      label: "b"
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: So what happens here is, the spread operator turns the object into an array? Which JSX interprets like props?

Comment: no it will not convert object into array, it will basically pass each key as a separate prop, it will be same as `<YAxis id='' label='' />` (shorter way of writing the same)

Comment: strange, i get this in my logs as a result: { id: '', label: '' }
no equal signs to be seen here

Comment: @TMvytKA9LgSVZ8Z7 See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Comment: check the updated answer, hope that will help you :)

Comment: thing is, we write jsx that will get conveted in `React.createElement(component, props, children)`, so props will be an object here. Either you can pass or transpiler will create one for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can [achieve](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) something similar using spread operator.

```
let props={a:1, b:2}

...

<MyComponent {...props}/>
```

Comment: weird, i was thinking of a more JSX type of syntax.
So you use the spread operator on an object?

Comment: @TMvytKA9LgSVZ8Z7 AFAIK this is the closest you can get to what you want. Yes you use spread.

Answer (score 1):

While the answers here cover the spread approach which is valid and works great, I would like remind that having too many props for a single component might indicate that this component suffers from too many variations, which in turn makes it really hard to maintain and extend.

In such cases you would like to consider the approach of [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) or "children as function" as it is sometimes called.

This approach allows you to keep your component logic and basic behavior in a single place, while the developers using it can use it in composition to alter the way the component renders and interacts with the surroundings. 
There is a great talk by [Kent C. Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/) about this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AiJ8tRRH0f8).

Hope this helps :)